# Assigning random edge weights to graph

Tags: r, igraph, sna

I want to create a random weighted and directed graph in R. I use the `erdos.renyi.game` to create a random directed graph, but I am unsure of how to create weights to the established connections:

```
library(igraph)
g01 <- erdos.renyi.game(25, 1/10, directed = TRUE)
```

How do I make this weighted?

Answer (score 5):

You can set the `weight` attribute for your edges to whatever you want. Here, I've set it to a uniform random weight between 1 and 5 and plotted so the edge width is equal to the selected random value:

```
set.seed(144)
library(igraph)
g01 <- erdos.renyi.game(25, 1/10, directed = TRUE)
E(g01)$weight <- runif(length(E(g01)), 1, 5)
plot(g01, edge.width=E(g01)$weight)
```

[image]